# FCKeditor arabic language not coming up

Tags: php, jquery, fckeditor

I am using FCKeditor in one of my projects.

```
<textarea name="Content_Arabic" id="Content_Arabic" cols="35" rows="4" class="txtfield"><?php echo (stripslashes(stripslashes($_POST['Content'])));?></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = new ew_DHTMLEditor("Content_Arabic");

    editor.create = function() {
        var sBasePath = 'FCKeditor/';
        var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('Content_Arabic', '100%', 350, 'Default');
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = sBasePath;
        oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
        oFCKeditor.rtl;
         oFCKeditor.ContentLangDirection='rtl';
        this.active = true;
    }
    ew_DHTMLEditors[ew_DHTMLEditors.length] = editor;

    ew_CreateEditor();  // Create DHTML editor(s)

    //-->
</script>
```

This loaded editor but it's still English style.

I want it to load as Arabic language style, from right to left.

Comment: is `oFCKeditor.rtl` a property or function or what? What are you expecting `oFCKeditor.rtl;` to do? If it's a function, you aren't calling it. If it's a property, you aren't setting it.

Comment: dear actually i dont know this editor too much. i jsut want to have it in rtl direction and for arabic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below assumes that you want this configuration statically for all the instances of the FCKEditor in your solution*.

Simply edit the file `/path/to/your_fckeditor_installation_dir/fckeditor.js` and change the following properties as follows:

```
FCKConfig.AutoDetectLanguage    = false ;
FCKConfig.DefaultLanguage       = 'ar' ;
```

**EDIT**

From your code above you just need the following lines (delete the rest):

```
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('Content_Arabic', '100%', 350, 'Default');
oFCKeditor.BasePath = 'FCKeditor/';
oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
```

And that's all!

*If you want this to change dynamically then you should alter your approach following [these](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/language-selection-fckeditor/) guidelines